# html table scraping using vba

Tags: html, vba, excel, web, screen-scraping

im trying to get the country from the tr tag but it just gives me the first row of the table how do i scrape a specific row

```
Sub ipsearch()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 2

    Do Until x = 4000   

        Dim ie As New InternetExplorer    
        ie.navigate "https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/" & Range("E" & x).Value

        Do    
            DoEvents        
        Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        Dim doc As HTMLDocument    
        Set doc = ie.document    
        Dim sDD As String

        sDD = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(, 0).innerText)

        Range("F" & x).Value = sDD    
        x = x + 1    
    Loop

End Sub
```

[image]
the blue bit is what I get and the yellow is what i want

Answer (score 1):

This is something, that will return "United Kingdom" in your example:

```
Sub ipsearch()
    Dim x As Long
    x = 2

    Do Until x = 4000
        Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
        ie.navigate "https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/" & "2.99.247.66"

        Do
            DoEvents

        Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Dim doc As HTMLDocument
        Set doc = ie.document
        Dim sDD As String
        ie.Visible = True

        sDD = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(1).innerText)
        Range("F" & x).Value = Split(sDD, vbCrLf)(5)

        x = x + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

In general, a few ideas for writing better code.

- It is really good to know what you are using - e.g., in your screenshot, the numbers from the IP are taken from the line above the blue, e.g. from "Details for 2.99.247.66".
- When you give code to StackOverflow, make sure to mention the additional libraries that your code is using. In your case these two:

[image]

Or make sure that your code uses late binding, thus the libraries should not be added.
 - In general, consider using `Long`, in stead of `Integer` - [Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)

---

- Format your code, when you submit it. It looks a bit better. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is the shortcut in StackOverflow.
- Use `Option Explicit` for VBA.
- Try to hardcode the variables in your question. In your case:

`"https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/" & "2.99.247.66"`

- Last but not least, a lot of web sites do not like being cralwed. Just fyi - https://www.google.com/search?q=is+crawling+legal

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot. It will fetch you the country name and place it in Range("A1").

```
Sub ipsearch()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/2.99.247.66"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    For Each post In html.getElementsByTagName("th")
        If InStr(post.innerText, "Country:") > 0 Then [A1] = post.ParentNode.LastChild.innerText: Exit For
    Next post
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

And to make it way faster, try the below one:

```
Sub ipsearch()
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object

    With HTTP
        .Open "GET", "https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/2.99.247.66", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In html.getElementsByTagName("th")
        If InStr(post.innerText, "Country:") > 0 Then [A1] = post.ParentNode.LastChild.innerText: Exit For
    Next post
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft XML,v6.0  ''or the version you have
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Output:

```
United Kingdom
```